# PhoneGap and UrbanAirship registering with alias (400 bad request error)

Tags: cordova, urbanairship.com

I'm successfully using the PhoneGap plugin (no longer officially supported by Urban Airship) on phonegap 1.9 for iOS.

When I register to UA without an alias all is well and I can receive test push notifications.  I tried sending the JSON payload along with the registration (used for alias/tags etc) and I'm receiving a 400 Bad Request error.

sending to: `api/device_tokens/DEVICETOKEN`

with JSON: `{"alias":1}`

I've set the request header to "`application/json`" as well.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks :)

Comment: SOLVED... see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  The alias value was not formatted correctly so in my case it works when I send the following (note the added quotes around the number 1):

```
{"alias":"1"}
```

So to conclude... here is what I added to the registration function in the PhoneGap UA Plugin to send an alias (this would be the same for tags etc):

```
var JSON_payload = {};
JSON_payload.alias = "1";   //add tags etc the same way

request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;");
request.send(JSON.stringify(JSON_payload));
```